# Extra white space in the webpage on the mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile

There is a weird gap on the right when the website is viewed on mobile devices, How to get rid of it? I want the webpage to fill the entire width of the screen.

I know, There are a dozen of question on the same exact thing and I've read plenty of them. None of them worked.

I'm also attaching an image of the problem.

Things that I've tried - `overflow-x: none` `margin: 0px` `padding: 0px` `width: 100%`

To see the problem, you could just go to the [website](http://lord-lavios.github.io/Tic-Tac-Toe/) and view it on a mobile device or the attached image or the dev tools.

Unfortunately, the css is unreadable, as I'm written it is sass, I'll attach the HTML and the sass in the question or you could just view the entire thing on [GitHub](https://github.com/Lord-Lavios/Tic-Tac-Toe/tree/gh-pages).

**HTML**

```
<header><h2>Tic Tac Toe</h2></header><button id="theme">Change Theme    </button>

<div id="main">

<div id="first" class="default">
</div>

<div id="second" class="default">
</div>

<div id="third" class="default">
</div>

<div id="fourth" class="default">
</div>

<div id="fivth" class="default">
</div>

<div id="sixth" class="default">
</div>

<div id="seventh" class="default">
</div>

<div id="eight" class="default">
</div>

<div id="nine" class="default">
</div>
</div>
```

**SASS**

```
 #first,#second,#third,#fourth ,#fivth,#sixth,#seventh,#eight,#nine
    display: flex
    justify-content: center
    position: relative
    align-items: center
    box-sizing: border-box
    float: left
    width: 33%
    height: 33.3333%
    z-index: 1000
```

[image: When viewed on chrome dev tools]

Comment: Why float *and* `display:flex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!

It was the `#theme`, it had an extra 10px margin to the right, I just removed it and it worked. Updated the website.

Thanks, anyways.

Answer (score 1):

On line 208 of `index.css` you define

```
.static #first, .static #second, .static #third, .static #fourth, 
.static #fivth, .static #sixth, .static #seventh, .static #eight, 
.static #nine {
    /*...*/
    width: 33%
    /*...*/
}
```

Change that to `width: 33.3333%;`. Should fix the slight tilt of the tiles to the left.

More importantly, add

```
html, body {
    min-width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

to make sure your page is always equal to viewport width.

As a sidenote, on line `189` of the same file, `overflow-x` should be `hidden`, not `none`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#main,#buttons,#scoreboard,head,button
{
  margin:0 auto; 
}
```